# Matlab: Meaning of '\a' or "alarm" in sprintf/fprintf

Tags: matlab, printf

In the documentations of `sprintf` and `fprintf`, in the list of special output format characters/operators, there is the `'\a'` character and they say it's "Alarm".

I tried printing it and it gives me an empty output.

```
>> sprintf('\a')

ans =



>>
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the ASCII `BEL` (0x07) character:

```
>> sprintf('\a')+0
ans =  7

>> a = sprintf('\a')
a =
>> b = char(7)
b =
>> a==b
ans = 1
```

It's normally used to make the console beep, but it doesn't do anything in my Octave command window.

Comment: To add to this answer, you can also do `char(sprintf('\a')+'0')` to verify that it is indeed 7.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Good idea.

Comment: Or just do `double(sprintf('\a'))`?